# Measure Theory - Convergence of functions with bounded integrals

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

A question I came across.

> Let $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$
>     be a $\sigma$
>    -finite measure space. Let $f_1,f_2,\dotsc:X\to\mathbb R$
>     be measurable functions such that $n^2\cdot\lVert f_n\rVert_2\leq1$
>     for all $n\geq1$
>    . Is it necessarily true that $f_{n}\rightarrow0$
>     a.e. for $n\to\infty$?

I'm pretty sure the answer is yes. My attempt at proving it:

It is given that: $\parallel f_{n}\parallel_{2}\leq\frac{1}{n^{2}}$

So we know $\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{lim}\parallel f_{n}\parallel_{2}=\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{lim}(\intop_{X}\mid f_{n}\mid^{2}d\mu)^{1/2}=0$

Since square root is a continuous function - $(\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{lim}\intop_{X}\mid f_{n}\mid^{2}d\mu)^{1/2}=0$

We would like to take the limit inside the integral. Fatou's Lemma tells us that for non-negative functions $\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{liminf}\intop_{X}\, f_{n}d\mu\geq\intop_{X}\,\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{liminf}f_{n}d\mu$
  so we can deduce that $\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{liminf}\mid f_{n}\mid^{2}=0$
 .
I am however stuck here since I want the same conclusion for the $lim$ and not $liminf$.

Any suggestions?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please take a careful look at my edits to your TeX. `\underset` isn't supposed to be used like that. And neither are `\parallel` and `\mid`.

Comment: Thanks! But why was the previous way wrong? It seemed to display alright...

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is incorrect. Note that when you claim
$$ \sum \int_X |f_n|^2 ~d\mu<\infty$$ this is not the same as $$\sum ||f_n||_2 <\infty.$$ In fact, in worst case the former sum can be like $\sum \frac{1}{n} = \infty$.

Also, let us note that it doesn't take all that effort to conclude $\lim \int |f_n|^2~d\mu = 0$, since this number is bounded by $\frac{1}{n}$ anyway.

The easiest way is probably to directly apply Fatou's lemma to the sequence of $L^1$ functions $|f_n|^2$.

Comment: You're right. I've updated my attempt but now I'm stuck as I don't in fact know that the sequence has a pointwise limit...

Comment: Hint: you only need $\lim |f_n|^2$ to exist. Note that you haven't used $X$ $\sigma$-finite yet.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I think i'm over complicating this. Can you perhaps elaborate some more?

Comment: If $X$ has finite measure, can you show $\lim |f_n|^2 = 0$ from what you have already? (Ans: yes.) Now how can you use $\sigma$-finiteness to complete the proof?

Comment: Do you mean something like:
Since X
  is $\sigma$
 -finite we know that for every integrable function and for every $\epsilon>0$
  there exists a set $K\subset X$
  of finite measure for which $\mid\intop_{X\setminus K}\, f\, d\mu\mid<\epsilon$
 . Since in general $\intop_{K}\, f\, d\mu\leq \mu(K)\cdot\underset{K}{sup}f$
 , we can deduce in our case that $\underset{K}{sup}\mid f_{n}\mid^{2}\rightarrow0$
 . But this doesn't quite give convergence on all of X
 ... sorry if this is easy...

Comment: Now use that $X$ is a countable union of sets of finite measure...

Comment: I've used that to obtain the set K. Maybe i'm lacking something basic here?

Comment: Note that the property you have shown ($\int_K f~d\mu \leq \mu(K)\sup_K f(x)$) holds for any $K$ of finite measure. So $\sup_K |f_n(x)|^2 \to 0$ on any $K$ of finite measure. If $X$ is a union of sets of finite measure, then...

Comment: Since $X=\underset{k}{\cup}X_{k}$
  all of finite measure then $\underset{\underset{k}{\cup}X_{k}}{sup}\mid f_{n}\mid^{2}=\underset{k}{sup}\{\underset{X_{k}}{sup}\mid f_{n}\mid^{2}\}$

 - This seems a little fishy to me...

Comment: ...$\sup_K |f_n(x)|^2 \to 0$ means $f_n(x)\to 0$ on $K$, so if $f_n(x) \to 0$ on all $X_j$ then $f_n(x)\to0$ on $\cup_j X_j$.

Comment: But if this argument were valid couldn't I deduce point wise convergence every time I have convergence in p-norm on a $\sigma$-finite space? Which is obviously false...

Comment: Why exactly is that obviously false? $L^p(X)$ is a Banach space, if a sequence converges in norm to $0$ then the sequence converges to $0$...

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your argument, but can't we take any sequence of functions whose graph moves around the line and gets successively smaller? It's integral will converge but it will not have a point-wise limit. For instance the "typewriter sequence" with indicator functions...